# React conditional useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm creating a handler for watching the click outside the component (click on document).

If the `myCondition === true` do some stuff on every click, otherwise ignore the click.

The question is:
Should I add/remove the `handleClick` on every `myCondition` changed
-or-
Just place `if` statement inside the `handleClick`?
Which is more preferred & why?

See my code below:

```
const [myCondition, setMyCondition] = useState<boolean>(false);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!myCondition) return;
    
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        // do some stuff ...
    }
    
    
    /* if meets the `myCondition` => attach the `handleClick`, otherwise detach it */
    
    // setups:
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    
    // cleanups:
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    };
}, [myCondition]);


const myConditionRef = useRef<boolean>(myCondition);
myConditionRef.current = myCondition;
useEffect(() => {
    const myCondition2 = myConditionRef.current;
    if (!myCondition2) return;
    
    const handleClick = () => {
        /* if meets the `myCondition` => do it, otherwise ignore */
        if (!myCondition2) return;
        
        // do some stuff ...
    }
    
    
    // setups:
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    
    // cleanups:
    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    };
}, []);
```

Note:
I wrapped the `myCondition` into the `useRef` so the `myCondition` can be consumed inside the second `useEffect` **without to be listed** on dependency array.

Comment: Why do you define `handleClick` inside the `useEffect`? Add and remove the event listener inside the useEffect, do everything outside?

Comment: Perhaps you can add your condition checking in your `handleClick` function instead?

Comment: because I want to listen click **outside** the component. I'm creating a DropdownMenu, so if the user click the document (outside the DropdownMenu), the menu will be closed.

Comment: If that's the case I think you can attach your click event as usual within a `useEffect` block. Within your click handler you would check if the `e.target` / `e.currentTarget` matches your `DropdownMenu`, otherwise close it.

Answer (score 0):

*If you want to use conditional change inside useEffect, declare a function inside the useEffect. For your component, you need to catch the event inside the function and check the current and the event.target. And change any state as per your need.*

```
const Action = ( {}) => {
  const ref = useRef();
 const [show, setShow] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (event) => {
      if (!ref.current || ref.current?.contains(event.target)) {
        return;
      }
      console.log("clicked outside of the component");
      setShow(false);
    };

    document.addEventListener("click", listener);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", listener);
    };
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <span ref={ref}>
    <span onClick={(_) => setShow(!show)}>
       Action
    </span> 
    {show && (
        <div>
          <span
            onClick={() => {
              setShow(false);
            }}
          >
            Select
          </span>
        </div>
      )}
    </span>
  );
};
```

Comment: Imagine there are a lot of dependencies: `ref` or `myCondition` or something else are **frequently changed**, the `addEventListener` & `removeEventListener` are also frequently executed. Is it expensive performing add/remove event listener?